# SSH интерфейс на роутере ZXHN H298A V1.1

Tags: ssh, роутер, zte

Нашёл у себя на роутере открытый SSH. И вот что странно: там две формы авторизации, первая - стандартная, для входа на сервер, а вторая - инородная (см. скриншот).

[image: странный вход]

В инородную я всё таки смог зайти с логином и паролем суперюзера (в ZTE сервисный пользователь), но потом перебрасывает в неизвестный мне CLI. При вводе знака ? в этот cli, выводится список доступных команд.

[image: enable]

Прочитал, что команда enable переводит в расширенный режим. Но она просит пароль, способ перебора не помогает. Надеюсь, кто-то знает что это за CLI (похоже на Cisco), и даст пароль :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот пароль - zte но толку нету, так как все полезные функции вырезаны прошивкой